# Where can I find more information of Gov2 specifications/documentation?

Tags: polkadot, pallet, governance

Other than the information presented (shown below), is there a way to keep track of the Gov2 technical specifications?

- https://polkadot.network/blog/gov2-polkadots-next-generation-of-decentralised-governance/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EF93ZM_P_Oc

Answer (score 3):

Specifically about the Polkadot Fellowship, which makes up a large part of it, you can take a look at the manifesto: https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/manifesto/blob/main/manifesto.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/5205) adding Gov v2 on Kusama. It might also be worthwhile checking out the [ranked_collective](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_ranked_collective/index.html) pallet, which seems crucial for the new governance model.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps overly complex, but until a nicely formatted page is available you can see this file here for the current parameters Kusama has been configured with:
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/governance/tracks.rs

e.g. for a small tip:

```
pallet_referenda::TrackInfo {
        name: "small_tipper",
        max_deciding: 200,
        decision_deposit: 5 * QUID,
        prepare_period: 4,
        decision_period: 28 * DAYS,
        confirm_period: 3 * HOURS,
        min_enactment_period: 28 * DAYS,
        min_approval: APP_SMALL_TIPPER,
        min_support: SUP_SMALL_TIPPER,
}
```